# Smooth DeviceOrientation Values

Tags: javascript, device-orientation, uideviceorientation

I'm trying to shift an image around based on the device orientation. But the values are very jumpy at rest, going between -1 to +2 with no movement, and I need a way to smooth it out a bit.

Is there an easy way to make this less jittery by averaging it out or something?

```
 init();
    var count = 0;

    function init() {
      if (window.DeviceOrientationEvent) {


        window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function(eventData) {
          // gamma is the left-to-right tilt in degrees, where right is positive
          var tiltLR = eventData.gamma;

          // beta is the front-to-back tilt in degrees, where front is positive
          var tiltFB = eventData.beta;

          // alpha is the compass direction the device is facing in degrees
          var dir = eventData.alpha

          // call our orientation event handler
          deviceOrientationHandler(tiltLR, tiltFB, dir);
          }, false);
      } 
    }

    function deviceOrientationHandler(tiltLR, tiltFB, dir) {

      var logo = document.getElementById("imgLogo");
      logo.style.webkitTransform = "rotate("+ tiltLR +"deg) rotate3d(1,0,0, "+ (tiltFB*-1)+"deg)";
      logo.style.MozTransform = "rotate("+ tiltLR +"deg)";
      logo.style.transform = "rotate("+ tiltLR +"deg) rotate3d(1,0,0, "+ (tiltFB*-1)+"deg)";
    }
```

http://codepen.io/picard102/pen/zvOVLx

Answer (score 0):

**Use [CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) to smooth out setting CSS values.**

You can try adding `transition: all 0.5s;-webkit-transition: all 0.5s;` to your logo. This will cause the browser to smoothly transition from one transform state to the next.

You might need to experiment a bit with this setting; and you may have to implement your own smoothing instead (in JavaScript, using [JavaScript-based animation](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/look-and-feel/animations/css-vs-javascript?hl=en)) if you're not happy with the results of CSS transition.

Comment: Ya, I tried to use transition to smooth it out, but the noise generated by the device values coming in so rapidly is a real hog. Fans spin up almost immediately.

Comment: What device are you on? I assumed you're on a mobile phone. Fwiw, you can store the values from the events you receive and only update for 30 or 60 frames per second, with smoothing the values (something you'd have to implement yourself).

Comment: Chrome Desktop MacBook. Also get similar results on iPhone as well.

Comment: You might want to search for game programming topics like smoothing of controller input values; there may be ready to use algorithms/libraries available. (Mathematically speaking, you're looking for exponential smoothing of a moving average: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing)